# How to save connections and reduce argument passing when always connecting to the same db in different functions?

Tags: python, refactoring, psycopg2

If you have a lot of functions connecting to the database, how do you do it so you don’t 1) pass a lot of arguments to each function 2) don’t establish (and close) a new connection each time.
In pythonic pseudocode

```
main():
    db = …
    host = …
    username = …
    password = …
    some_function(db, host, username, password)

some_function(db, host, username, password):
   try:
   con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'".format(db, username, password, host))
   cur = con.cursor()
   cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {}.{};".format(schema, ‘myTable’))
   function2(cur.fetchall(),db, host, username, password)
…
    except:
        …

Function2(db, host, username, password):
   try:
     con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'".format(db, username, password, host))
     cur = con.cursor()
     cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {}.{};".format(schema, ‘otherTable’))
     function3(cur.fetchall(),db, host, username, password)
     …
    except:
        …
```

It’s unfortunate that `some_function()` and `function2()` are almost exactly the same (though the `…` inside would be different). I’m wondering how can I extract this code to reduce redundancy? At the very least how do I reduce the function signatures with `db, host, username, password`?

I thought of putting these as global variables so at least I wouldn't have to pass the variables to each function that needs the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a singleton db class that takes the arguments once, and then you only ever call getInstance() to get the object and open() to get the connection.

Comment: It's not that straightforward in `Python`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760685/creating-a-singleton-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do

```
class Database():
    def __init__(self):
        db = ....
        host = …
        username = …
        password = …
        self.con = psycopg2.connect("dbname='{}' user='{}' password='{}' host='{}'".format(db, username, password, host))
        self.cur = con.cursor()

    def function1(self):
        try:
            self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM {}.{};".format(schema, ‘myTable’))
            msg = self.cursor.fetchall()
        except:
            ...
```

With this you only have to `connect` once and you can access `cursor` and `database` using `self.cur` and `self.con` respectively from within your class.
You can make any number of functions now, similar to `function1` through which you can access the database .